# If $f: (X, M) \to (Y, \tau)$ is measurable, then for all Borel sets $B \subset Y$ it is true that $f^{-1}(B) \in M$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I am lost with this proof, the problem is as follows:

Let $(X,M)$ be a measurable space, $(Y, \tau)$ be a topological space, and $f:X\to Y$ be measurable. Then, for any Borel set $B \subset Y \Rightarrow f^{-1}(B) \in M$.

I know that, since $f$ is measurable, then it must be true that for any set $U \in \tau \Rightarrow f^{-1}(U) \in M$ by the definition of measurable function. But this seems too simple and I am almost sure I am missing steps.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is just the definition of measurability but if your definition says inverse images of open sets are in $M$ then here is a proof: the collection of all Borel sets $B$ in $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(B) \in M$ is a sigma algebra containing all open sets, hence all Borel sets.

Comment: So basically it is asking to prove that $X$ is measurable? But that is already in the prompt

Comment: @TheBosco It is very easy to verify that the class of sets I have defined is a sigma algebra. Let me know if you have difficulty in verifying this and I will be glad to help.

Comment: It's not that, but how this fits with the rest of the proof. Let's call the collection of Borel sets $B$ in $Y$, $\mathcal{B}_Y$. Then, after proving that this is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra, this means that any Borel set $B$ is indeed in $\mathcal{B}_Y$ and, by the definition of a measurable function we can complete the proof. My question is, how do we know that $\mathcal{B}_Y$ is $\tau$?

Comment: The definition of Borel sigma algebra in a topological space is it is the sigma algebra generated by open sets. @TheBosco

Comment: I am still somewhat lost. So, we prove that the set you defined is a sigma algebra containing all Borel sets. Then, this means that all Borel sets in $\tau$ are also in $\mathcal{B}_Y$ (I am trying to do this, but I am struggling). Then the result follows with the definition of measurable function?

Comment: $\mathcal B_Y$ is the notation for the Borel sigma algebra of $Y$ which is the sigma algebra generated by open sets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{B}_f$ be the family $\{B \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[B] \in M\}$.

Then $\mathcal{B}_f$ is a $\sigma$-algebra as $f^{-1}$ preserves unions, complements etc. and $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. [insert your own proof here.]

By your definition of measurable function: $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{B}_f$.

The Borel sigma algebra $\mathrm{Bor}_Y$ of $Y$ is by definition the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\tau$. $\mathcal{B}_f$ is **one** $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\tau$ so by the minimality $\mathrm{Bor}_Y \subseteq \mathcal{B}_f$ and this means by definition of the latter that $f^{-1}[B]\in M$ for all Borel subsets $B$ of $Y$.

Comment: Then, for the proof that $\mathcal{B}_f$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. But how can I prove from this that $Y \in \mathcal{B}_f$?

Comment: @TheBosco what are the axioms for $\sigma$-algebra? $Y \in \mathcal{B}_f$ is easy as $f^{-1}[Y]=X$ and $X \in M$.

Comment: for the sigma algebra $M$ of the set $X$, they are 
$X \in M$, closure under complements and closure under countable unions. I thought it was as you say, but why can I just define that $f^{-1}[Y] = X?$

Comment: @TheBosco You should know ( or prove) that $f^{-1}[\bigcup_n A_n]=\bigcup_n f^{-1}[A_n]$ and $f^{-1}[Y \setminus A]= X \setminus f^{-1}[A]$. The other axioms follow from that.

Comment: For example, can I state the following?
For any collection of sets $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ where each $B_i \in \mathcal{B}_Y$. Then, $\forall i \in I \ f^{-1}(B_i) \in M$ and since $M$ is a sigma algebra, $\bigcup_i f^{-1}(B_i) \in M$. But after here I'm lost

Comment: @TheBosco then note that by the identity I gave this means $f^{-1}[\bigcup_i B_i] \in M $ so that $\bigcup_i B_i \in \mathcal{B}_f$ which is what you had to show. Etc.

Comment: I know that it works with the identity, but why does the identity work?

Comment: @TheBosco show two inclusions. It’s pure set theory.